# A children's sci-fi book about children on the moon

Tags: story-identification

I remember a book as a kid about moon inhabitants.  The book was about a couple of the children who would have adventures, and I think maybe even traveled in space ships... I remember absolutely loving the books, but I was like 9, so I can't really remember any other details besides that.  This would have been in the early 80's, but the books could have been much older.

Answer (score 3):

One of the classic stories with two children having an adventure on the moon is the Robert Heinlein novel [Have Space Suit - Will Travel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Have_Space_Suit%E2%80%94Will_Travel). This is one of several novels that are characterized as the ["Heinlein Juveniles"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinlein_juveniles).

In the novel, the main character Clifford "Kip" Russel wins a space suit in a contest. He ends up being kidnapped along with a young girl "Peewee", and an alien "Mother Thing" and taken to the moon. They manage a short lived escape and hike across the surface of the moon before being recaptured and transported to Pluto.

Other Heinlein novels involve scenes on the moon. The novel [The Rolling Stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rolling_Stones_%28novel%29) starts on the moon with a family that lives there, until they buy a ship and head out on an adventure. The short story [The Menace From Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Menace_from_Earth) is set entirely on the moon.

Comment: Those were my first thoughts as well, the Heinlein YA ones. Quite a few of them featured similar themes, the other main "moon" one that I remember was [Rocket Ship Galileo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Ship_Galileo).

Comment: I love that book. It's one of my favorite Heinleins, and much better I'm sure than whatever book the OP is remembering. Probably not Kip and Peewee, because they were not series characters, they were just in that one book.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the first SF book I remember reading: The Wonderful Flight to the Mushroom Planet by Eleanor Cameron - first in a series. Two kids build a spaceship in their back yard and travel to a moon/planetoid somewhere not that far from Earth. I don't remember the whole story but it involved leaving a chicken behind when they went home!